# Using Symfony to get post data sent by Backbonejs

Tags: php, symfony, backbone.js

I am new to backbone & symfony (as well as open source), and I am trying to make a sample application based on these 2 frameworks. I have an HTML page on front end (using backbone) which I send a request to backend system (using symfony) by calling model.save, model.destroy, etc. On backend system I have an action of a controller with the declaration as below:

```
public function createAction(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
```

but when I var_dump the $request I cannot find out the POST parameters that being sent from front end (neither $_REQUEST, $_POST). 
I am wondering how could I get the POST parameter using Symfony?

Here is my code of Backbone

```
var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'http://localhost/bookkeeper/web/app.php/',
    defaults : {
        title : '',
        description : '',
        pages : 0
    }

});

var book = new BookModel();
var bookDetails = {
    title : 'Test backbone test add new',
    description : 'test add new',
    pages : 354
};
book.urlRoot = 'http://localhost/bookkeeper/web/app_dev.php/create';

book.save(bookDetails, {
    success : function(model, response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error : function(model, response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

I also appreciate if you could provide me a tutorial to solve this.
Thank you for your help

PS: I could get the POST data if I use a HTML form by calling

```
$request->request->get('description')
```

Comment: Can u provide your backbone js collection or model script?

Comment: @MarcelDjaman I have already updated, please have a look.

Comment: sorry @geraintdong see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make your way through the [Symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) which will help you with these questions and give you a fuller understanding of the way Symfony works rather than just cherry picking solutions from tutorials for your specific problem. Your questions will be answered by the chapter on the [Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) and you may also want to look into [Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) and [Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) which will help with the processing and validation of the data coming in from Backbone / AJAX. All of the book is a great tutorial and should help you get started with the Symfony framework as a whole.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have looked into the book and tried what it suggests but it does not help. :( hope you have a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the time try this

```
book.save(bookDetails, {
    silent  : false,
    sync    : true,
    success : function(model, res) {
        if (res && res.errors) {
            console.log('no way, crap!');
        } else {
            console.log('yes i did it!');
        }
    },
    error: function(model, res) {
        console.log('error!');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a Symfony Controller with an action that can handle an AJAX request. Inside your action, you can check if your Request object is AJAX or not via `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()`.

For more you have to check Symfony documentation regarding controllers and the routing: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html